# integration of $\frac{x}{(x^2-1)^\frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: integration

When I use the substitution $u=\cosh x$ to integrate $\frac{x}{(x^2-1)^\frac{1}{2}}$, I get $\frac{1}{2}(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}-\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}})$ but when I check online the answer is $\sqrt{x^2-1}$ which is much tidier. I'm probably being thick, but how can my answer be simplified to $\sqrt{x^2-1}$? and if it can't, is there a reason why I got a different answer to the integral?

Comment: You could have done an algebraic sub. Let $u=x^2-1$.

Comment: but can the answer I got be simplified to the one online?

Comment: Your answer is equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is correct:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}-\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}})&=\frac{1}{2}(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}-\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}\times \frac{x-\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x-\sqrt{x^2-1}})\\
&=\frac{1}{2}(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}-\frac{x-\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x^2-(x^2-1)})\\
&=\frac{1}{2}(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}-x+\sqrt{x^2-1})\\
&=\sqrt{x^2-1}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $u = x^2 -1$ then $du = 2x\  dx$ and

$$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{u^{1/2}} du$$

Alternatively,as you suggested letting $x = \cosh t$ then $dx = \sinh t\  dt$ and

$$\int \frac{\cosh t \sinh t}{(\cosh^2 t - 1)^{1/2}} dt = \int \cosh t\  dt = \sinh t + C$$

Answer (score 1):

If $x=\cosh u$, then

$\displaystyle\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx=\int\frac{\cosh u}{\sinh u}\cdot\sinh u du=\int\cosh u du=\sinh u+C=\sqrt{x^2-1}+C$

Comment: why does sinh u= (x^2-1)^1/2?

Comment: Since $\cosh^{2}u-\sinh^{2}u=1, \sinh^{2}u=\cosh^{2}u-1=x^2-1$.